# How to get only one iteration in ifelse statement

Tags: r, string, if-statement, break

I am trying to pass a string through a function to call a column from a data frame. I made a very simple if-else function to make sure the foundation was working before adding complexity. Essentially, if the column name is found within the data frame, print "Hi", if not, print "No". The function correctly identifies if the column name is in the data frame but it prints a duplicate "No".

I have tried using `if(){}else(){}`

Using `ifelse()`

Using break and next with the if(){}else(){} method

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind("a" = 1:5,
                    "b" = 6:10))

testingIf <- function(x){
  if(x %in% colnames(df)){
    print("Hi")
  }
  else{
    (print("No"))
  }
}
testingIf("a")
testingIf("This is true")
```

`if(){}else(){}`
-This was my initial attempt and if the 'if' is true it works as intended, but if the 'if' is false it prints out [1] No [1] No.

Using `ifelse()`
-Prints out [1] Hi [1] Hi when true and [1] No [1] No when false

Using break and next with the `if(){}else(){}` syntax
-This works so far as it give me the correct output but I get

> "Error: no loop for break/next, jumping to top level"

, which makes me feel like I am missing something.

Comment: Try defining the function using `print("No")` instead of `(print("No"))`. For reference, compare the result of `print("no")` to `print(print("no"))`, which is essentially what `(print("no"))` is doing.

Comment: `break` and `next` have no meaning within `if`/`else`, it *should* cause an error: their meaning is only intended within *"a 'for', 'while' or 'repeat' loop"* (ref: [`?break`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/Control)). As to seeing it twice: the first is from the `print`, and the second is also from `print` which *invisibly* returns its string. Because (as bouncyball just said) you did `(print(...))`, it turns the invisible *visible*. And when lacking a `return` statement, the function will return the value of its last expression, which is `(print(...))`.

Comment: You'll get the same double-print thing if you change from `(print(...))` to `print(...)`, and then call `(testingIf(...))`.

Comment: NotThatKindODr, do the comments make sense? Do they resolve the issue? There are some votes-to-close, so it would help if what has been said so far does not start to address things. (It can be frustrating when votes-to-close start, whether justified or otherwise, just trying to get your feedback/attention before it goes much further.)

Comment: Thank you for all the help! Removing the extra () from print() did clear up the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function can be made simpler by using the `ifelse()` function.

Using your dataframe `df <- as.data.frame(cbind("a" = 1:5,"b" = 6:10))`, we can rewrite your function as:

```
testingIf <- function(x,dt){
    ifelse(x %in% colnames(dt),"Hi","No")
}
```

Now testing the code, we have:

```
> testingIf("a",df)
[1] "Hi"
> testingIf("This is true",df)
[1] "No"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! I do think ifelse looks better, do you know of any limitations of using it versus the long way?